# Select - option, cross browser support

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, firefox, select

my task: link in my solution page bcs of my newbie-reputation 8(
my solution: http://bit.ly/1gFZDDM

I am not able to manage HTML, I can work only with CSS and Javascript/jQuery. I know it easier to use unordered-list, but I can't. I have few problems which I dont know how to solve.

1 - There should be small gap/space between underlined options and borders around "option-box". I dont know how to short this line or how to apply padding to whole box.

2 - My option-box borders doesn't look like in my task and it doesn't react to my border-lef/right of my option{...}. Again is there a way how to apply changes for that whole box?

3 - Biggest problem, my cross-browser totaly suck! Firefox looks almost fine with just problems above, but IE and Chrome absolutely ignore my styling of option-element. It looks like it ignores:

`select option[data-class="flag-cz"]{
    background-image: url("image/cz-flag.png");
    background-position: 10px center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }`

but this works:
`select option[value=""]{display:none;}`

Could the problem be in [data-class="flag-cz"]? There is written a lot about Chrome non-support of option manipulating, but I found for example: http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/ which for even in Chrome/IE... I just dont know how to get that few informations from this tool.

thx for any help my skills suck too much

Comment: When it comes to apply customized style to SELECT cross browser, you have to forget it. Use instead default styling or customized SELECT element like in you provided link

Comment: _“I am not able to manage HTML, I can work only with CSS and Javascript/jQuery”_ – JavaScript/jQuery _can_ manipulate the HTML structure of the document for you dynamically; in fact, quite a few solutions for “custom select fields” already exist … so I’d suggest to do some research on that.